# What does this "に" do in this sentence?

Tags: particle-に

I'm translating this sentence

> たまにはひとり気まま **に** ブラつくのもいいか？

and I understood something like *Is it okay to wander alone and carefree sometimes?*, but I'm not sure because I don't understood the function of that に in this case, Someone can explain me how it works here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I'm mistaken, it should simply be the adverbial に, transforming it into an adverbial phrase. See also: https://www.imabi.net/adverbsii.htm